# PEP8, vim, and block of code

Tags: python, vim, pep8

Sometimes, I am working on old Python code where PEP8 was not followed at all.  I could run [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/) on the whole code but that would generate a large diff. What I want is to be able to select a block of Python code (via vim) and have just that block auto configured so that it obeys PEP8.

With C++, you can use astyle with `:20,40!astyle` to do just that.

Is there a vim equivalent?

*Note that this is a clear example of not reading the man page for autopep8...*

Comment: Did you even try something? Like `:20,40!autopep8 -i -` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, from reading autopep8's documentation, something like:

```
:20,40!autopep8 -i -
```

or (that was actually my first idea):

```
:20,40!autopep8 -
```

should work.

The general mechanism is called "filtering" and you can read all about it in `:h filter`.

Comment: The latter works fine, the former causes an error on the version of autopep8 I have.